# Beautiful Soup Returns Empty Value

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to retrieve a Parcel value on this [website](http://50.17.237.182/PIM/?search=400%20Van%20Ness%20Ave) using Beautiful Soup.
[image]

However, it returns an empty list (instead of 0787001 as a value in a list) when I run the following code:

```
import bs4, requests
html = requests.get("http://50.17.237.182/PIM/?search=400%20Van%20Ness%20Ave")
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html.text, "html.parser")
soup.select("table.reportData:nth-child(90) > tbody:nth-child(1) > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(3)")
```

Does anyone have the solution to this?

Comment: There is no `table.reportData` in the file.

Comment: Hi @DYZ. There should be a table named "reportData" in the file. I have updated the problem description.

Comment: Well, I guess there isn't, as `soup.select("table.reportData")` returns a `[]`.

Comment: The website seems to use JavaScript for loading the content of the page. Try to view the webpage with JavaScript disabled in order to see what really loaded to python.

Comment: Thank you @ChristosPapoulas. I viewed the webpage with JS disabled, and the parcel value didn't load. I am still looking for a way to retrieve this value though.